# Using Windows media foundation

Tags: c++, windows, video, ms-media-foundation

Ok so my new gig is high performance video (think Google streetview but movies) - the hard work is all embedded capture and image processing but:

I was looking at the new MS video offerings to display content = Windows Media Foundation.

Is anyone actually using this ?

- There are no books on the topic.
- The only documentation is a developer
  team blog with a single entry 9 months old.
- I thought we had got past having to learn an MS api by spying on the com control messages!
- Is it just another wrapper around the same old activeX control?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you read [Media Foundation Programming Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms697062%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)? It looks pretty complete.

Comment: It's Windows7 only, a lot of industrial customers are on XP. Think I will stick to OpenGL

Answer (score 8):

I read the Media Foundation Programming Guide, and it's as complete as everything else is w/ MS, in that you have all the information you need, no clue on how to find it, and no idea what's important when.

I'm trying to use MMF, but I'm currently not getting anywhere, and am thinking that going back to DirectShow might be the better approach as there is more example code with explanations.

No, it does *not* appear to be just another wrapper around the same ActiveX controls.

Answer (score 3):

To get started with Media Foundation you might want to [read this.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735656592) Media Foundation was first introduced in Windows Vista. Thus, you must have Vista or later versions of Windows to develop Media Foundation apps. If you are targeting Windows XP users then, D-Show might be a better option.